# Fastest way to get the total number of elements in a sorted array that belong to an arithmetic progression series

Tags: python, math

Given the first element and common difference of AP series. How can i find the total number of elements in a sorted array (**Repetitions are allowed**) that belong to the AP series. Is it possible to do it in less than `O(N)`?

what i've tried so far

```
if (arr[i]-a)%d == 0: 
   count+=1
```

`Constraints: 1<=d<=10^5 , 0<=a<=10^5`

Ex: `a = 1` , `d = 3`

```
[1,2,4,6,7,7,9,10]
```

Answer: `5`

basically i want to find total numbers that are of the form `a+dx` , so step size can be `d`

Comment: You want to be able to add a number at the end and then determine whether it is still part of the sequence without even looking at it. If that was possible, then it would also be reversible: all the way back to a single element. I.e., you look at the first number *only* and say, "right, this is indeed a proper sequence". No, I don't think that is possible.

Comment: If you didn't count the repetitions, you could potentially do some arithmetic like `((myList[-1] - a)/d) + 1` but this only works if the last element is part of the sequence. I am not sure it's possible in less than `O(N)`.

Comment: Just not possible without looking at each element in the array, so `O(N)` is as good as it gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there is a faster than `O(N)` solution to this problem, unless you remove the repetitions.

That being said, this is the fastest implementation that I could come up with:

```
def is_part_of_sequence(a, d, x):
    return (x%d) == a

def get_length(a, d, l):
    # going to be using this a few times in this function
    ips = is_part_of_sequence

    # get the length of the list
    n = len(l)

    # get the first value in the sequence
    min_seq_ind, min_seq_value = next(
        (i, v) for i, v in enumerate(l) 
        if v == a
    )

    # get the last value in the sequence
    max_seq_ind, max_seq_value = next(
        (n-i-1, v) for i, v in enumerate(reversed(l)) 
        if ips(a, d, v)
    )

    min_length = ((max_seq_value - a)//d) + 1  # this is the minimum length

    # check to see if min_length is the correct answer- if so, short circuit
    if min_length == (max_seq_ind - min_seq_ind + 1):
        return min_length

    count = 2
    count += sum(1 if ips(a, d, l[i]) else 0 for i in range(min_seq_ind+1, max_seq_ind))

    return count
```

The only optimization here is that in the case that the sequence contains no duplicates, this algorithm is constant time because it can short circuit.